# return values on or condtion in php

Tags: php, return

I have two functions which will run based on a conditon.
The code is like

```
$contact=($this->function() or $this->function1())

public function()
{
 some codes
return contact;
}

 public function1()
  {
 some codes
 return contact;
   }
```

It returns me bool true or false in $contact. I want to return the values. what to do?

If I give like this

```
$contact=$this->function() or $this->function1()
```

It does not check the function1() if the function() is false.

Comment: So which value should be returned? What are you trying to get in `$contact`?

Comment: or is used like `||` ? and `return $contact;` ?

Comment: -1. Provide concrete code, not something that won't even compile.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use boolean operator or, result of

```
$this->function() or $this->function1()
```

is boolean.
In PHP 5.3 you can use ternary operator like this

```
$contact=$this->function() ?: $this->function1();
```

if earlier versions

```
if (!($contact=$this->function() )) $contact=$this->function1();
```

But, generally speaking, I think you must review your functions and change something in their flow. Must probably, make one out of these two and take decision inside this function.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return a value and use `OR` operator
One Way is to set a variable and value it in the function like this:

```
    $ret = "";
function ()
{

    $this->ret = "foo";
    return contact;
}

function1() {
    $this->ret = "Bar";
    return contact;
}

$a = function() or function1();
unset($a);
$newRet = $ret;
```

See here for more details:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check both functions regardless then test for both and save in seperate variables their result, then use those two variables in your if comparison

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$contact = $this->A() or $contact = $this->B();
```

Or

```
$contact = $this->A() ?: $this->B();
```